# Python how to find duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

When I try to use `duplicated` function does not work.

Here is my query example:

```py
query = """
SELECT
  variable1,
  variable2,
  variable3,
  variable4

FROM source.table
"""
df = spark.sql(query)
```

When I try to find dups using this function, it does not work:

```py
# Selecting duplicate rows based
# on list of column names
duplicate = df [df .duplicated(['variable1', 'variable2'])]
 
print("Duplicate Rows based on variable1 and variable2:")
 
# Print the resultant Dataframe
duplicate
```

I got this error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'duplicated'`

Do you know why? And how I can create a pd dataframe based on my current DF?

Comment: Why do you think that a DataFrame object has a "duplicated" method?

Comment: see available DataFrame methods [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/dataframe.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark dataframes and pandas dataframes (and pandas-on-spark dataframes) are different. If you have pandas installed and available, you may be interested in [converting to a pandas on spark dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark.html) and then using [pandas on spark duplicated](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.duplicated). I believe the code would be something like this:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
ps_df = df.to_pandas_on_spark()
ps_df[ps_df.duplicated(['variable1', 'variable2'])]
```